# Generic method for Calendar view appium android

Tags: android, testing, calendar, automation, appium

I am automating android app using Appium (java).
In calendar view , I found some links and made this method:

```
public static void setDatePicker(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver,String mon,String dt,String year){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']")).sendKeys(mon);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']")).sendKeys(dt);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='2']")).sendKeys(year);
    }
```

However ,this is not working properly. 
Can anyone tell me what mistake I am doing in this or any workaround for calendar view that is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*@class='android.widget.NumberPicker' znd @index='0']")).sendKeys(mon);
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Because I used it exactly as it is and threw an exception . org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Argument was an invalid selector

Comment: yes, try again with the updated answer. Can you please share the screenshoot of your UIAutomator?